# What is the probability that from 23 people 2 people have their birthday on the same day?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, birthday

What is the probability that from 23 at least people 2 people have their birthday on the same day. Assume that the year has 365 days and that all the birthday combinations have the same probability.

Can anyone solve this?

Comment: This is a very famous probability problem.  It's easiest to determine the complementary probability: no matches among 23 people.

Comment: I have gotten that long but I am uncertain how to proceed¨

Comment: It is well known:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out

Comment: It is also known under "birthday-paradox" because it is surprising at first sight that the probability is already exceeding $0.5$.